# Larger uploads not posting on nginx + php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm

I'm running into an issue where images < 2MB are uploading without issues, but 2MB images are not uploading via form posts.

**Configuration:**

*php.ini*

```
upload_max_filesize 96M
post_max_size   96M
memory_limit    128M
```

*nginx.conf*

```
client_max_body_size 96M;
client_body_buffer_size 96M;
```

I'm not seeing any error messages in my nginx or php logs.  Any ideas where to look for more information on where this is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a PHP info page and verify that the web server is actually reading in the php.ini that you are updating, some Operating systems (i.e.. RHEL) let you install multiple versions of PHP and keep separate configurations.

The PHP info page should allow you to verify your increased values are being read.

Comment: On my phpinfo() page, I can confirm the 96M max size setting

Comment: @arby can you scan through the settings and verify nothing is set to ~2MB?